# Creating Order not setting CustomerID in Inserted Record

Tags: acumatica

I'm not sure why this is being difficult, but I can't seem to insert a new SOOrder with a customer ID in the SOOrder page. I'm trying to do this programmatically creating a new instance of SOOrder and using that to insert and save the new order.

If I insert a fresh SOOrder object into the (Current)Document view, then set the customer ID, run an update, and try to save, I get the error that CustomerID cannot be null. Looking into the object during runtime after the update is executed, it shows the Inserted row with a CustomerID of null:

```
...
SOOrder order = new SOOrder();
SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
order.OrderType = "SO";
graph.CurrentDocument.Insert(order);                
order.CustomerID = project.CustomerID;
graph.CurrentDocument.Update(order);
graph.Actions.PressSave();
...
```

[image]

If I try to first set the CustomerID in an SOOrder object, then insert that object into the (Current)Document view, it gives me a more complex error in relation to the customer ID:

```
...
SOOrder order = new SOOrder();
SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
order.OrderType = "SO";     
order.CustomerID = project.CustomerID;
graph.CurrentDocument.Insert(order);
...
```

[image]

Is there something special I need to do to get a CustomerID to get set within the view object so I can save it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will assigning **order** variable the result of the `graph.CurrentDocument.Insert(order);` command resovle the error?

```
SOOrder order = new SOOrder();
SOOrderEntry graph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
order.OrderType = "SO";
order = graph.CurrentDocument.Insert(order);                
order.CustomerID = project.CustomerID;
graph.CurrentDocument.Update(order);
graph.Actions.PressSave();
```

Comment: Hey Ruslan, good to hear from you! Thank you! That worked. I keep forgetting that the .Insert() command returns the object inserted. Are there any guidelines to when I should set the object = to the result of it being inserted into a view?

Comment: I would say always after insert/update if you intend to use the object's values later (after the insert/update)

Comment: 1. create the empty record using 'new' operator. 2. populate the key fields that are not auto-generated, for SOOrder there are two key fields, OrderType which is not auto-generated so you populate it, the other one OrderNbr is auto-generated so you don't populate it. 3. insert the record. 4. populate all other fields except auto-generated keys (OrderNbr in this case) 5. update the record and invoke the graph save action